# Unload userform when user activates another program

Tags: vba

I have a userform that I'd like to have close when the user changes from excel to another program.
I have tried using the sheet deactivate event in ThisWorkbook, but it isn't doing the trick.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

Comment: Simply opening another application does not deactivate the worksheet. The worksheet is still active.  There is, not to my knowledge, any event native in Excel that will capture when the application loses focus.

Comment: you might be able to do it using a window handle and the WinAPI but it is beyond my area. Can I ask why? Seems complicated :P

Comment: I think you can get this with `GetForeGroundWindow` or `GetActiveWindow` but still need a way to trap the event...

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As LongPtr

Sub test()
Dim wbHwnd As LongPtr
Dim fHwnd As LongPtr
Dim aHwnd As LongPtr

    'replace with timer class that ticks
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test", , True

    wbHwnd = Application.hWnd
    fHwnd = GetForegroundWindow
    aHwnd = GetActiveWindow

    If wbHwnd <> fHwnd Then
        Debug.Print "Lost focus"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Has focus"
    End If


End Sub
```

This just gets the Hwnd of the current application and compares it against the foreground window. Rather than use Application.Ontime it may be better to use a timer class that ticks at set intervals.

Also, you can be more specific and use Hwnd for the userform rather than the Application. and if you keep the Ontime event remember to deactivate the timer on workbook close or similar.

EDIT:

Assuming the Userform has a unique caption you can find the HWnd using the USerform caption

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "User32.dll" () As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "User32.dll" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "User32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" _
  (ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal WindowName As String) As LongPtr



Sub test()
Dim wbHwnd As LongPtr
Dim fHwnd As LongPtr
Dim aHwnd As LongPtr
Dim ufHwnd As LongPtr

    'replace with timer class that ticks
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "test", , True

    wbHwnd = Application.hWnd
    fHwnd = GetForegroundWindow
    aHwnd = GetActiveWindow
    ufHwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", UserForm1.Caption)

    If wbHwnd <> fHwnd Then
        Debug.Print "Lost focus " & wbHwnd & " " & fHwnd & " " & aHwnd & " " & ufHwnd
    Else
        Debug.Print "Has focus " & wbHwnd & " " & fHwnd & " " & aHwnd & " " & ufHwnd
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: User forms don't have an HWND.

Comment: Your right, I'm thinking of WinForms. It still does what OP asked for in question :)

Comment: Yes, +1 for creative solution.  I still wonder if there is a way to trap this like an event though.

Comment: This might have some more info http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/activate-excel-application-event-t3476939.html